# Change cursor to loading animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor, loading-animation

I've got a few loading bars that appear during any postbacks. How can I use CSS to have the cursor change into a custom loading animation? In examples I've come across, I can only turn the cursor into other preset images (such as an hourglass). Is it possible for me to use a custom gif as the cursor?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533287/css-custom-cursors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

The `cursor` CSS property can take a `url()` value:

```
.my-cursor {
  cursor: url("mysite/cursor.png"), default;
}
```

Different browsers have different foibles. I haven't messed with this in years so I'm not sure what you might encounter as to browser support, and of course on mobile devices it's not relevant.

Comment: Please add a summary of the link

Comment: @NoamHacker wow that was a long time ago :) I had pretty much just started using the site. I would downvote the answer now.